# Prevent IME (Soft keyboard) from leaving the application

Tags: android, android-input-method

I want to prevent users from leaving the application (client requirement, not a mass public application).

But the IME allows the user to reach settings by pressing some touch. How can I block this without developing my own keyboard ?

As far as I understand from Google documentation, there is not much I can do because the IME is the first component to receive the screen inputs and it is the IME which decides what inputs my application receives.

Any pointer appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There's really no way to prevent somebody from being able to leave your app without a custom rom. However, Android 5.0 Lollipop allows device owners to pin the screen. For example, conferences that hand out tablets to their attendees are using the feature to restrict tablet usage to the conference app.

Here's a good write up to the feature:
http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/10/17/lollipop-feature-spotlight-screen-pinning-allows-you-to-lock-your-device-to-a-single-app-before-handing-it-to-a-friend/

Alternatively you could try one of the various launchers on the Play Store that use alternative locking strategies, but in my experience there's often a way around them unless they simply lock the device completely.

Comment: thank you for your information. Have you ever work with any Mobile Device Management ?